# my buttons in tkinter don't work! tried everything

Tags: python, button, tkinter, grid, toplevel

I'm trying to write a game. So far I've made a grid of buttons, but I can't seem to make the buttons work the way i want them to. I think the problem lies in x and y not being connected to the actual buttons, but I've tried everything and I can't seem to make it work. Below is my latest attempt.

```
import tkinter as tk

jeopardy = tk.Tk() 
jeopardy.geometry("2000x1000")
jeopardy.configure(background="blue")

#------------Questions---------------
def questions():
    global x
    global y
    global sort

    for sort in (x, y):

        if x == 0:
            if y == 0:   
                extra_window = tk.Toplevel(jeopardy)
                label2 = tk.Label(extra_window, text="question")
                label2.pack()

            elif y == 1:
                extra_window = tk.Toplevel(jeopardy)
                label3 = tk.Label(extra_window, text="question")
                label3.pack()

            #etc

#------------Buttongrid---------------
tk.Grid.rowconfigure(jeopardy, 0, weight=1)
tk.Grid.columnconfigure(jeopardy, 0, weight=1)

frame= tk.Frame(jeopardy)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

for x in range(5):
    tk.Grid.rowconfigure(frame, x, weight=1)
    for y in range(5):
        tk.Grid.columnconfigure(frame, y, weight=1)
        text = 100*(y+1)
        btn = tk.Button(frame, text=str(text), command=questions) 
        sort = btn.grid(column=x, row=y, sticky="nsew")



jeopardy.mainloop()
```

Comment: `doesn't work` is not describing the problem. What exactly is not working?

Comment: @HenryYik: "buttons that will each reveal a question when clicked" doesn't work.

Comment: @HenryYik the toplevel window is not opened when the button is clicked. If i assign x=0 and y=0 inside the questions-function it works, which means the code for the toplevel is correct. However i want a new toplevel window to be displayed for coordinates (x,y) with x and y 0 through 5, so for (0,0) , (0,1) etc.

Comment: your `x,y` is the last assigned value of your for loop which is always `4,4`.

Comment: @HenryYik I see, yeah that seems to be the case. Is there any way I can assign the questions function for the coordinates i actually want to use?

Comment: Yes - add the command when you create the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of repetition and useless `globals`. You can use `lambda` functions to pass parameters to your callback function. I edited your code to illustate it:

```
import tkinter as tk 

jeopardy = tk.Tk() 
jeopardy.geometry("1000x500")
jeopardy.configure(background="blue")

#------------Questions---------------
def questions(x, y):
    questiontext = f"question{x}{y}"

    extra_window = tk.Toplevel(jeopardy)
    lab = tk.Label(extra_window, text=questiontext)
    lab.pack()

#------------Buttongrid---------------
tk.Grid.rowconfigure(jeopardy, 0, weight=1)
tk.Grid.columnconfigure(jeopardy, 0, weight=1)

frame= tk.Frame(jeopardy)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

for x in range(5):
    tk.Grid.rowconfigure(frame, x, weight=1)
    for y in range(5):
        tk.Grid.columnconfigure(frame, y, weight=1)
        text = 100*(y+1)
        btn = tk.Button(frame, text=str(text), command=lambda x=x, y=y: questions(x, y))
        btn.grid(column=x, row=y, sticky="nsew")

jeopardy.mainloop()
```

`lambda x=x , y=y : ...` avoids x, y being always the last values of the loop metioned by @Herny Yik's comment.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you were planning on doing by creating new `Toplevel` windows, but the following will change the `Button`s text when you click on them (without relying on global variables):

```
import tkinter as tk

jeopardy = tk.Tk()
jeopardy.geometry("800x800")
jeopardy.configure(background="blue")

ROWS, COLS = 5, 5
# You'll want to populate this with real questions.
QUESTIONS = [['question {:2d}'.format(j*COLS+i) for i in range(1,COLS+1)]
                for j in range(ROWS)]


tk.Grid.rowconfigure(jeopardy, 0, weight=1)
tk.Grid.columnconfigure(jeopardy, 0, weight=1)

frame = tk.Frame(jeopardy)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

for x in range(ROWS):
    tk.Grid.rowconfigure(frame, x, weight=1)
    for y in range(COLS):
        tk.Grid.columnconfigure(frame, y, weight=1)
        text = 100*(y+1)
        btn = tk.Button(frame, text=str(text))
        btn.grid(column=x, row=y, sticky="nsew")

        def show_question(btn=btn, x=x, y=y):
            btn.config(text=QUESTIONS[x][y])

        btn.config(command=show_question)

jeopardy.mainloop()
```